# How to update user field, multi user field, taxonomy field & multi taxonomy fields using GRAPH

Tags: taxonomy, user-accounts, microsoft-graph

I am using MS documentation mentioned at
"https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/listitem_update".

All other types of fields are getting updated but user and taxonomy fields always fail.

**Please note that I have also tried to give same json item for user/taxonomy field for update which comes out after any other successful update request.**

For Example: all of the below listed attempts failed.

PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/fields
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "Color": "Fuchsia",
    "Quantity": 934,
    **"Owner1": "Himanshu Pandey",//this fails
    "Owner2": "Himanshu Pandey|(guid for User)",//this fails
    "Department1": "Human Resource", //this fails
    "Department2": "Human Resource|(guid for human resource item)",//this fails**
}

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45707051/create-sharepoint-list-item-with-lookup-field-with-microsoft-graph/51242644#51242644

The answer:
This works with people fields where the multiple selection option is DISABLED. So if you have a person field which allows one person only, the following works.

```
"{columnName}LookupId": id
```

Additionally, the id still needs to be the SP ID and not the graph user GUID. This ID changes from site to site.